# Calculate GFLOPS in Cuda

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing

I am working on a cuda project where I am comparing the performance of various CUDA implementations of matrix multiplication.The point is I am trying to calculate the GFLOPS of the GPU but I can't figure out how to do that.I have managed the time needed to perform the multiplication so far using cuda events as shown:

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    cudaEventRecord(start);
    MatrixMulKernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>> (Ad, Bd, Cd, M, N, K);
    cudaEventRecord(stop);



    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float milliseconds = 0;
    float seconds = 0;
    float GFLOPS=0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
    seconds = milliseconds *  pow((float) 10,-3);;
```

Is there some sort of equation to calculate the GFLOPS?!
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you work out a couple of low-dimensional examples (paper and pencil) you can figure out that the number of floating point operations for matrix multiplication is

```
long NumOps = N*N*(2*N-1);
```

where I have assumed for simplicity that the matrices are `N*N`.  Exercise for you: generalize this to arbitrary array sizes for matrices A (of dimensions, N1*N2) and B (with dimensions, N2*N3). Giving `A*B` (with dimensions N1*N3).

Keep in mind that in the literature on the subject that the number of floating point operations, `O(N^3)`, is often simply taken as, `NumOps = N^3`, when profiling matrix multiplication.  So just keep this in mind if you compare your results to other published values.

Either way, Gflops can be calculated as:

```
float gflops = (float)NumOps/time_per_multiply_inSec/1e+9;
```

There are also some [good notes here](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~norbert/CompPhys/chapter10.pdf).

Comment: OK, I've managed to get the number of operation but whenever I try to print, the matrix multiplication isn't performed and I get something like this:
Unhandled exception at 0x0ff4b971 in parallel.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
Can this happen as result of printf?!

Comment: You are accessing the address 0x5. Probably some object is NULL and maybe you have tried to de-reference it?  Run your program with a debugger and it should be clearer what is happening. Specifically, it will give you a stack trace and tell you about the state of the variables.

Comment: OK after checking and getting the result, What should the range of the output to make sure I'm getting correct answer?! The result I got is 0.17 so please advise.

Comment: @omarsafwany: how could anyone answer that? You haven't said the size and type of of the matrix and the device you are running this on.